# PyImport_Import fails to import module that contains imports

Tags: python, c++, python-c-api

I'm working on a c++ project that needs some functionalities included in a python library (scipy.stats).
I created my python script that uses the libray and my idea is to pass the data from c++ to the python script, call the function and get the return value from python.
But then when I do PyImport_Import(pName), it returns null because the module start with an import. If I use another script that doesn't start with an import it works fine.
What am I doing wrong?

chi2.py:

```
from scipy.stats import chi2, chi2_contingency


def chi2Test(alpha):
# contingency table
    table = [   [2556, 9327, 1028, 564],
                [770,  2991,  322, 164],
                [433, 1566, 182, 97]
                ]
    stat, p, dof, expected = chi2_contingency(table)
    # interpret p-value
    if p <= alpha:
        return False
    else:
        return True
```

(table is just a placeholder, in the future it will become a parameter)

main.cpp:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <random>
#include <windows.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include "pyhelper.hpp"

int main() {

    CPyInstance hInstance;

    CPyObject pName = PyUnicode_FromString("chi2");
    CPyObject pModule = PyImport_Import(pName);

    if (pModule)
    {
        CPyObject pFunc = PyObject_GetAttrString(pModule, "chi2Test");
        if (pFunc && PyCallable_Check(pFunc))
        {
            CPyObject pArgs = PyTuple_New(0);
            CPyObject pArg = PyFloat_FromDouble(0.5);
            PyTuple_SetItem(pArgs, 0, pArg);

            CPyObject pValue = PyObject_CallObject(pFunc, pArgs);

            bool res = PyObject_IsTrue(pValue);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("ERROR: function getInteger()\n");
        }

    }
    else
    {
        printf_s("ERROR: Module not imported\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

CPyInstance and CPyObject are 2 classes defined as specified here: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/820116/Embedding-Python-program-in-a-C-Cplusplus-code

Thanks to anyone that can help or has suggestions to give.
(It is the first time I'm working on c++ with python embedded)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the solution. This happens because the debug symbols of numpy and scipy are missing. Setting visual studio in release mode solved the problem